# Can there be more TCP sockets than the port number?

Tags: linux, sockets, ssl, tcp

I'm on Linux and am opening up SSL connections to 993.  My program crashes around 993 open sockets.  I remembering seeing some documentation on TCP programming somewhere discussing a limit like this.  My question is:  Am I recalling something correct and if so how does this work?  Or am I flat out making stuff up.

Comment: Most likely you are reaching the limit of open files. It's usually 1024. Try increasing it: `ulimit -n 4096`.

Comment: Are you using `select()` to handle socket activity? There's a limit of 1024 FDs for that as well.

Comment: Your crash is likely unrelated to the max number of open files. You likely have a real bug to fix first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between the number of simultaneously open descriptors or sockets, or about the number of descriptors passed to calls such as `select` or `poll` on one side, and a particular port number on the other side.

You see a value 993 most likely because it is 1024 minus some other completely unrelated descriptors/sockets that were open on the system before.

All the limits discussed apply within a single process so you should be able to figure this out, for example using `strace`